# Why wont redirect work after fetch call inside getserversideprops

Tags: javascript, redirect, next.js

The main issue I am facing is whenever I call a redirect outside a fetch function it works but as soon as I put that redirect inside a response of a fetch function it wont redirect the page.`your text`.

I was trying to allow google sign up to create accounts for the users. If a user uses google sign in it allows the person to go to the newaccount.js file. Once inside that path it checks if that google username exists in the database . If it does,It redirects the user to the home page . If not it asks the user to enter a password and save that username and password on the database.

The code :

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
    const session = await getSession({ req })
    // console.log("this first runs")
    // console.log(session)
    if (!session) {
        console.log("this not running")
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/',
                permanent: false
            }
        }
    } else {

        let username = session.user.name
        let email = session.user.email
        let body = { username, email }
        await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/checkuser", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        }).then((res) => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result)
                if (result.success == true) {
                    if (result.exists == false) {
                        console.log("user added success fully")
                    } else {
                        return {
                            redirect: {
                                destination: '/',
                                permanent: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("something went wrong")
                }
            });
    }

    return {
        props: { session }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not return the `redirect` in your `else` statement. One way to solve this is by `await`-ing all asynchronous actions, like so:

```js
} else {
  let username = session.user.name
  let email = session.user.email
  let body = { username, email }
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/checkuser", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  })
  const result = await res.json()
  console.log(result)
  if (result.success == true) {
    if (result.exists == false) {
      console.log("user added success fully")
    } else {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: '/',
          permanent: false
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log("something went wrong")
  }
}
```